# websocket_url for solana_client::tpu_client::TpuClient

Tags: solana-client

I'm wondering which URL I need to provide as `websocket_url` when I call `TpuClient::new()`?

```
use solana_client::tpu_client::{TpuClient, TpuClientConfig};
use solana_client::rpc_client::RpcClient;

fn main() {
    let rpc_client = RpcClient::new("https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key={API_KEY}");
    let tpu_client_config = TpuClientConfig::default();
    let tpu_client = TpuClient::new(
        rpc_client.into(),
        "wss://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key={API_KEY}",
        tpu_client_config,
    );
}
```

This looks wrong to me because it's the RPC websocket URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the solana_client [rust crate documentation](https://docs.rs/solana-client/latest/solana_client/tpu_client/struct.TpuClient.html#impl-TpuClient%3CQuicPool,+QuicConnectionManager,+QuicConfig%3E), this is the correct syntax.

See this function prototype:

```
pub fn new(
    rpc_client: Arc<RpcClient>,
    websocket_url: &str,
    config: TpuClientConfig
) -> Result<Self>
```

You are passing in the websocket url as the second argument as it expects. The TPU client can get actual TPU address and port information via that rpc / websocket connection.

TL;DNR: You're doing the correct thing here!